# How to reduce weight of text underline in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, text

I am editing a web mockup in Photoshop. I have underlined text in the character window to represent a hyperlink. The default underline for my Arial 11 pt text  appears to be two pixels tall and I would like to reduce the underline height to one pixel. Is it possible to reduce the height of the default text underline or do I need to actually create a 1px tall line and place it under the text?

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible with the underline option. Of course, there's nothing stopping you from drawing your own 1px line and not using the underline option.

Answer (score -1):

Remove underline option for text. Take new layer create line and cut as per the required height.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted but then not sure what you mean by "cut" either?